# Compatibility of textbox AutoCompleteMode and keyPress event, C#

Tags: c#, autocomplete, event-handling

I have a textbox tbx. For it I had an event handler:

```
public void tbxPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("message 1");
        if (e.KeyChar == 13) // i.e. on Enter
        {
            MessageBox.Show("message 2");
        }
    }
```

and it worked perfect until I set AutoCompleteMode parameter of tbx.

After that auto-complete works fine, but on Enter i don't get "message 2". ... the hell?!

VC#2008EE

Comment: Are you getting "message 1"?  If so, then have a message box which shows the value of KeyChar.  My guess is that you are not getting "message 1" either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the KeyDown event and check e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter.